Combobox dropdown "underlapping" another combobox in lower row
I am working with aura components and lightning:combobox.
I need to create a table and have made a row-based data structure in backend, sent it to the front end and displayed in html/css. All works fine except for the comboboxes. Screenshot to show the problem

As you can see, the dropdown menu is hidden below the other comboboxes in the rows below. I have tried playing a lot with relative positions and z-indexes but without any result. I have also implemented the same in another component without any issue and i fail to find any possible reason beside the fact that, in this case, im displaying the rows programmatically via an aura:iteration. Code below:
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-1 slds-small-size_1-of-1 slds-p-around_small">
                <!-- First box -->
                <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
                    <div class="slds-scrollable_x">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.data.detailRows.length > 1}">  <!-- if data present -->
                            <div class="first_box">
                                <div class="slds-scope">
                                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_cell-buffer slds-size_1-of-1">

                                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.data.detailRows}" var="row" indexVar="index"
                                                        start="0">
                                            <aura:if isTrue="{!index == 0}">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset"
                                                    style="position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 3; height: 30px !important">
                                                    <th class="slds-col first-column">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate"
                                                             title="{! row.rowTitle }">
                                                            {! row.rowTitle }
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th class="slds-col data-column">

                                                        <div class="slds-truncate"
                                                             title="{! row.resultPY.periodName }">
                                                            {! row.resultPY.periodName }
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th class="slds-col data-column">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate"
                                                             title="{! row.targetCY.periodName }">
                                                            {! row.targetCY.periodName }
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>

                                                    <aura:iteration items="{!row.periods}"
                                                                    var="detail">

                                                        <th class="slds-col data-column">
                                                            <div class="slds-truncate"
                                                                 title="{!detail.periodName}">
                                                                {!detail.periodName}
                                                            </div>
                                                        </th>

                                                    </aura:iteration>

                                                    <th class="slds-col data-column">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate"
                                                             title="{! row.status.periodName }">
                                                            {! row.status.periodName }
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>

                                                    <th class="slds-col text-column">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate"
                                                             title="{! row.action.periodName }">
                                                            {! row.action.periodName }
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>


                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                            </aura:if>

                                            <tbody>
                                            <aura:if isTrue="{!index != 0}">
                                                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset slds-size_1-of-1">
                                                    <td class="slds-col first-column">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{! row.rowTitle }">
                                                            {! row.rowTitle }
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="slds-col data-column">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate">
                                                            <lightning:input label="{! row.resultPY.periodName }"
                                                                             variant="label-hidden"
                                                                             name="{! row.resultPY.supportData }"
                                                                             value="{! row.resultPY.dataValue }"
                                                                             readonly="{!or(row.resultPY.readonly, or(not(v.isUserOfSameCompany), v.readonly))}"
                                                                             oncommit="{!c.saveDetailChange}"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="slds-col data-column">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate">
                                                            <lightning:input label="{! row.targetCY.periodName }"
                                                                             variant="label-hidden"
                                                                             name="{! row.targetCY.supportData }"
                                                                             value="{! row.targetCY.dataValue }"
                                                                             readonly="{!or(row.targetCY.readonly, or(not(v.isUserOfSameCompany), v.readonly))}"
                                                                             oncommit="{!c.saveDetailChange}"/>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>

                                                    <aura:iteration items="{!row.periods}"
                                                                    var="detail">
                                                        <td class="slds-col data-column">
                                                            <div class="slds-truncate">
                                                                <lightning:input label="{! detail.periodName }"
                                                                                 variant="label-hidden"
                                                                                 name="{! detail.supportData }"
                                                                                 value="{! detail.dataValue }"
                                                                                 readonly="{!or(detail.readonly, or(not(v.isUserOfSameCompany), v.readonly))}"
                                                                                 oncommit="{!c.saveDetailChange}"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </aura:iteration>

                                                    <td class="slds-col data-column">
                                                        <div class="">

                                                            <lightning:combobox
                                                                                variant="label-hidden"
                                                                                class="hide_label"
                                                                                name="{! row.status.supportData }"
                                                                                value="{! row.status.textValue }"
                                                                                disabled="{!or(row.status.readonly, or(not(v.isUserOfSameCompany), v.readonly))}"
                                                                                placeholder="Select a Color"
                                                                                options="{! v.statusLights }"
                                                                                onchange="{!c.saveDetailChange}" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td class="slds-col text-column slds-size_2-of-12">
                                                        <div class="slds-truncate">
                                                            <lightning:input type="text"
                                                                             label="{! row.action.periodName }"
                                                                             variant="label-hidden"
                                                                             class="input-z-index"
                                                                             name="{! row.action.supportData }"
                                                                             value="{! row.action.textValue }"
                                                                             readonly="{!or(row.action.readonly, or(not(v.isUserOfSameCompany), v.readonly))}"
                                                                             oncommit="{!c.saveDetailChange}"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>

                                                </tr>

                                            </aura:if>
                                            </tbody>

                                        </aura:iteration>

                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </aura:if>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

As of now, no particular css has been applide beside a few lines to make the first column of the table sticky.
does anyone have a pointer for me?

Do you have tried to give z-index to combobox?

I have tried giving it a z-index, positive or negative and making the parent div/td/tr relative. No luck so far. It seems like it's the dropdown menu that is not overalpping correctly though, not the combobox input. I have no idea what to try next
